# How to use startmanagingcursor in fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

How can I use startmanagingcursor in fragment? Because I need to pull data from SQLite in Fragment but I cannot use startmanagingcursor in it.

Here is my coding

```
 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbUtil.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbUtil.fetchNews(getArguments().getString("title"));
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);
        newsTitle = cursor.getString(0);
        dbUtil.close();
 }
```

Comment: Its clearly mentioned in docs, > startManagingCursor (Cursor c)
> > This method is deprecated. Use the new CursorLoader class with
> LoaderManager instead; this is also available on older platforms
> through the Android compatibility package. Then why you want to go with deprecated method?

Comment: You don't. That's an `Activity` method and it has been deprecated. Use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since everyone else seems to want to preach at you and not give you an answer, I'll actually answer your question (then preach :p).

```
getActivity().startManagingCursor(yourCursor);
```

It's as simple as that.

As others have noted, it's deprecated and a `CursorLoader` is recommended for many reasons... keeping data processing off the UI thread being the major one.

But if you truly need/want to use `startManagingCursor` in a fragment, the above snippet is how you would do it.

Given the further information you have posted, another issue might be where you are trying to call your database from.  You should not use the `onCreate` method in a fragment class (at least for these operations), you should use `onActivityCreated`.  That way you are certain that the activity that controls your fragment has finished setting itself up before you try and use anything associated with it.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118) got still this error even I added getActivity().startManagingCursor(myCursor). Can you show me any usage for CursorLoader?

Comment: That error isn't about your cursor... its about the DB. Looks like it can't open it for some reason.

Comment: public DatabaseUtil open() throws SQLException {
  mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(myContext);
  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }